# IE10 stop scroll bar from appearing over content and disappearing

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

If you go to any website with content that causes a vertical scroll bar in ie10 (desktop) such as http://www.buildwindows.com/ you'll notice that the scroll bar only appears when you hover over the window.

Is there anyway of forcing the scroll bar to always display? I'm worried that it makes it less obvious that there is more content further down the page.

Thanks

Comment: I've found that it only disappears when adding

@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

To the CSS as per the "fix" for windows 8  that ignores the meta viewport tag (see http://timkadlec.com/2012/10/ie10-snap-mode-and-responsive-design/)

Comment: Thanks to Pedro below for the answer. Sill unsure why I got downvoted for a totally reasonable question.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that-might-be-bootstrap

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There is a custom vendor-prefixed CSS property to set:

```
html {
   -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

Other options include `auto`, `none`, `scrollbar`, and `-ms-autohiding-scrollbar`. The latter causes the behavior you're experiencing.

An excerpt from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx), specifically the abovementioned `scrollbar` value:

> Indicates the element displays a classic scrollbar-type control when its content overflows.
>
> Unlike `-ms-autohiding-scrollbar`, scrollbars on elements with the `-ms-overflow-style` property set to `scrollbar` always appear on the screen and do not fade out when the element is inactive.

Comment: Yet more time spent getting a site to display correctly in IE.  +1, worked for me.

Comment: This works great, but I'm curious as to what happens on a windows phone or tablet? On my computer, I want to get rid of this behavior because the scrollbar appears over the content. Do you know if there's a way to disable it for touch-only devices, like tablets and phones?

Comment: @Redtopia - Usually, on mobile devices, the scrollbars are unobtrusive and have a default behaviour of auto-hide. If you find other option for -ms-overflow-style that suits you better, just create the same .html rule for touch-devices or different screen sizes with a different value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect answer. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, the media query will prevent the scroll for disappearing when screen is larger than 992px. (I assume Windows mobile device need this for hiding the scroll bar. this is why I've made the media query).

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;  
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  @-ms-viewport {
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the css style

`overflow-y:scroll;`

will cause the element it is set for to always have vertical scrollbar

Comment: you might have to use overflow:scroll;, IE might not implement the overflow-y style. Also what are you applying the style to?

Comment: Then too it does not work. Show me a website where you have implemented it and shall check in IE10. Applying this style to 1. HTML, 2. Body, 3. HTML, body.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this isn't about forcing a scroll bar when there isn't enough content to cause it. This is about stopping IE10 from hiding the scroll bar until hovering over the window. Thinking about it, I think this happens on a mac but feels better implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I added this on the html element, i.e. html{-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;} and it worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

Adding this META-Tag works:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think though that unless there's some code to specifically stop this from happening I'll just live with it rather than changing the rendering mode.

Comment: This might solve the problem, but then you're stuck using the IE9 rendering engine, which is probably not a good idea.