# Scrollbar displayed incorrectly in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have used `bootstrap css` for my website. In `Internet Explorer 10` the vertical scroll-bar disappears default. It appears only any operations made on the page like (mouseover, scroll, etc).

It appears the scroll-bar by the following image.

[image]

Is it default functionality in `IE 10` ?

If it is an error how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

In IE 9 it looks like following.

[image]

Comment: IE rocks whatever you do it seems to irritate you in 1000 different ways. Can you post some code.

Comment: @joyBlanks So many css files I have and didn't add any special code for that. In IE 9 it displays asusual

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE10, but in IE11 this is also the case, see my printscreen of the bootstrap website. This is also the case on many other websites. [Here is a SO topic about this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that).

[image: Bootstrap in IE11]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already find the solution from the above link

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your css file:

`@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}`

It should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. I already fine that