# window doesn't resize when scrollbar automatically added in IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, html

i have an angular project and my view works fine in chrome and firefox but in IE 11 when the scrollbar appears the view doesn't resize automatically so i have some component covered by scroll bar

the menu css:

```
#menu-principal .navbar-lower {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  min-height: 35px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1029;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that

Comment: position fixed is tricky. I suggest you set overflow-y: scroll to the <body> tag.

Comment: thank's for the help , like is mentioned in the link is was @-ms-viewport{ width: auto; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding
@-ms-viewport{ width: auto; }