# Off canvas scrolling issue with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I am working with a Joomla 3 website and experiencing some issues with the scrolling functionality of an off-canvas sidebar.

It works fine in Chrome and FF, however in IE the visible scroll bar won't scroll when you try move it by clicking your pointer and dragging. It works if you scroll with the mouse wheel, but not the cursor.

The website [can be seen here](http://uber.demo.joomlart.com/). It's the slide in menu to the right.

Is it a css or javascript issue?

I have contacted the developers of the template and I'm awaiting a response. Just wondering if anybody else can shed some light as to why it won't work?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the main scroll bar is over the menu scrollbar.

Comment: This [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that) in stefan.s answer, all you have to do is add `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;` to the `html` element.

Comment: It should be the `html` element.

Comment: Add: `html { -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar; }`

Comment: Thanks I got it by adding `body.off-canvas-effect-4.off-canvas-right.off-canvas-open {
 -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar !important;
}`