# On IE11, strange scrollbar appearing

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have my body as overflow:hidden.
If some content is overflowing the viewport, on specific zoom levels I have a vertical scrollbar appearing. Only on IE11.
The scrollbar has no use at all, the 'cursor' is filling the scrollbar completely.

[image]

Any idea on how to remove this scrollbar?

It seems more like a bug of IE11 but maybe there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in here: [Scrollbar overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that?rq=1)
Adding `@viewport{ width: auto !important; }` in my CSS file fixed the issue